# How to use itemcget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Yes, I did some research about this but I don't understand it, http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M56 it explains what it does but I don't understand what `TagId` is.

Can anyone give me some examples like getting an image from a canvas?

I tried `Canvas.cget("image")` but got an error

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-image"
```

Comment: If you don't want the question to be downvoted, a good thing to do would be to show some code of what you tried.

Comment: We need to see how you're creating the canvas, how you're creating items on the canvas, whether you're creating an object with the "image" tag, when you're calling `itemcget`, etc.

Comment: When you call `.create_image(...)` like `item_id = canvas.create_image(..., image=image, tag="abc")`, then `item_id` is the *ID* of the image item, and a tag *"abc"* is assigned to this item as well.  Then you can use `canvas.itemcget(item_id, "image")` or `canvas.itemcget("abc", "image")`.  `item_id` or "abc" is the `TagId`.

Comment: @acw1668 That's the answer that I was looking for! If you want you can answer this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `.create_image(...)` like:

```
item_id = canvas.create_image(..., image=image, tag="abc")
```

then `item_id` is the *`ID`* of the image item, and a tag *`"abc"`* is assigned to this item as well.

Then you can use `canvas.itemcget(item_id, "image")` or `canvas.itemcget("abc", "image")` where `item_id` or `"abc"` is the `TagId` mentioned in the document link.